# Getting ERR_DNS_FAIL when loading a local webserver page?

Tags: windows, browser, dns

When I go to a page hosted on a machine on a local network, I get a "The page cannot be found" error with "ERR_DNS_FAIL" in the title.

Any ideas what this is or why I am getting it on my computer? I've tried in Firefox, IE and Chrome.
Other computers on the network load the page just fine.

I'm pretty sure it is from the hostname. I am able to access the page if I browse to it using the IP of the machine. However, it has two hostnames and both are giving the ERR_DNS_FAIL error.

I tried restarting the browsers or rebooting the machine, but neither helped.

EDIT: ISSUE RESOLVED ON ITS OWN!

Comment: This error could be generated by any proxy you're going through. Can you open up a command line and nslookup the hostname?

Answer (score -1):

usually when you have a VPN or proxy turned ON..this could happen..turn them OFF and reload

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This may be an issue IF the VPN or proxy are misconfigured. A properly running VPN or proxy should not have this issue. By disabling them you are merely masking the true issue.